# How to create Feature Vector with top Words (Feature selection in scikit-learn)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, feature-selection

Im using scikit-learn to create Feature vectors of documents.
My goal is to create a binaryclassifier(Genderclassifier) with these Feature vectors.

I want to have as a feature k-top Words, so the k highest counted Words from both labeldocuments (k=10 -> 20 features, since 2 labels)

My both Documents (label1document, label2document) are filled with instances like this:

```
user:somename, post:"A written text which i use"
```

My understanding so far is that I use all text from all instances from both documents to create a vocabulary with countings(countings for both label so I can compare the labeldata):

```
#These are my documents with all text
label1document = "car eat essen sleep sleep"
label2document = "eat sleep woman woman woman woman"

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=1)

corpus = [label1document,label2document]

#Here I create a Matrix with all the countings of the words from both documents  
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

Question1:What do I have to put in fit_transform to get the most counted words from both labels??

```
X_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k=2).fit_transform( ?? )
```

Since in the end, I want Training data(instances) like this:

```
<label>  <feature1 : value> ... <featureN: value>
```

Question2: How do i proceed from there to get this Training data?

Oliver

Answer (score 5):

```
import pandas as pd

# get the names of the features
features = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

# change the matrix from sparse to dense
df = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns = features)

df
```

which will return:

```
    car eat essen   sleep   woman
0   1   1   1   2   0
1   0   1   0   1   4
```

Then get the most frequently used terms:

```
highest_frequency = df.max()
highest_frequency.sort(ascending=False)
highest_frequency
```

Which will return:

```
woman    4
sleep    2
essen    1
eat      1
car      1
dtype: int64
```

Once you have the data in a `DataFrame`, it is easy to massage it into the format you'd like, such as:

```
df.to_dict()
>>> {u'car': {0: 1, 1: 0},
 u'eat': {0: 1, 1: 1},
 u'essen': {0: 1, 1: 0},
 u'sleep': {0: 2, 1: 1},
 u'woman': {0: 0, 1: 4}}

df.to_json()
>>>'{"car":{"0":1,"1":0},"eat":{"0":1,"1":1},"essen":{"0":1,"1":0},"sleep":{"0":2,"1":1},"woman":{"0":0,"1":4}}'


df.to_csv()
>>>',car,eat,essen,sleep,woman\n0,1,1,1,2,0\n1,0,1,0,1,4\n'
```

Here is some useful [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction).